# ubuntu 14.04.01 closing lid freezes laptop

Tags: laptop, suspend, freeze

I have a thinkpad yoga s1 with i7 cpu, hd4400 graphic card and Ubuntu 14.04.01 installed. The computer freezes when closing lid but if I suspend it before I close the lid, it won't freeze next time when I open the lid. 
I've tried everything I can. I already updated the graphic card driver with the software provided by intel. Nothing changed. Any help please?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad T430.  Very annoying.